# PayPal Express Checkout: Setting logo_image and name using REST API

Tags: api, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, express-checkout

PayPal's Express Checkout [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/customize-the-checkout-flow/#pass-experience-profile-options) says that you can customize the checkout using the Experience API. And when you go to the Experience API [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payment-experience/#definition-presentation), you see the ability to set a custom name, logo_image, and more.

In our implementation, hiding the shipping fields (no_shipping: 1) works - and that uses the Experience API - but setting the name and logo_image does not.

Code below. Does anyone know if there's a way to set name and/or logo_image?

```
payment: function(data, actions) {
         return actions.payment.create({
            payment: {
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: { total: '9.99', currency: 'USD' }
                    }
                ]
            },

            experience: {
                name: 'Custom Name',
                presentation: {
                    logo_image: 'https://i.imgur.com/customimage.png'
                },
                input_fields: {
                    no_shipping: 1
                }
            }
        });
    },
```